# Nested Select Statements in LINQ to Entity Without Unnecessary Loads

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I want to perform a nested select statement in linq the form of:

```
select * 
from table_a 
where w in (select w 
            from table_b 
            where x in (select x 
                        from table_c 
                        where z in (select z 
                                    from table_d 
                                    where z = z)))
```

The problem is, the only way I can figure out how to do that is by loading the results from table_b and table_c, which adds an unnecessary expense. For example, say I am attempting to load all of a customer's orderdetaildetails. The following code will load ALL of MyCustomer's orders and ALL of each order's orderdetails and, only then, all of each orderdetail's orderdetaildetails:

```
   customer MyCustomer;        //Entity customer already loaded.

   var query = MyCustomer.orders.SelectMany(order => order.orderdetails).SelectMany(od => od.orderdetaildetails);
```

Another approach is to use the .Include function. However, this also loads each level:

```
var query = MyCustomer.orders.CreateSourceQuery().Include("orderdetails.orderdetaildetails");
```

Both of these functions load unnecessary data. The first, `SelectMany()`, actually makes separate roundtrips to the database for each navigation level and then for each returned entity (save entities on the last navigation level). Include() makes one trip to the database and does one giant join statement. This is a little better, but still unseemly.

Is there a way to reach the ordetaildetails level (from customer) WITHOUT loading orders and orderdetails into memory AND in one trip to the database only?

Thanks guys - Lax

Answer (score 2):

This should get you the orderdetaildetails for a given customer without unnecessary loading.

```
customer MyCustomer;        // Entity customer already loaded
var orderDetailsDetails = context.OrderDetailsDetails
    .Where(odd => odd.OrderDetail.Order.Customer.CustomerPK == customer.CustomerPK);
```

It looks like you have lazy loading enabled which means that as soon as you access the customers orders EF goes off to the database to get them for you. It's the same when ever you access the orders orderdetails. An alternative method similar to what you used would be.

```
var query = context.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerPK == customer.CustomerPK)
    .SelectMany(c => c.orders)
    .SelectMany(order => order.orderdetails)
    .SelectMany(od => od.orderdetaildetails);
```

Comment: Lazy loading is now disabled. Your method still produces a large join (for me, at least). When I said 'load' I didn't mean it would necessarily be placed into the context but that those records would be pulled into memory in any fashion.